# Unable to get OpenCL running on Ubuntu 16.04 machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, gpu, amd-graphics

I have set up an Intel machine using a simple Intel Atom based CPU as well as an AMD RX Vega 56 GPU.

I want to create full load on the GPU, and try out some of my OpenCL/C programs. (I also want to use hashcat.)

I installed the Ubuntu 16.04 Server because the AMDGPU-Pro driver is only compatible with this version.
I followed the install instructions and used `./amdgpu-pro-install -y -opencl=rom` parameteres.
It has been installed successfully.
I also installed the ocl-icd-dev, clinfo, opencl-headers packages and mesa-ocl- or something like that.

To try out if it works i just tried the "clinfo" command.
Providing the following output:

```
    root@atomium:/home/chairman/opencl-experiments/tools-master# clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2117.10)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              <error: no devices in non-default plaforms>
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
```

So i cloned some OpenCL examples from this repository to check it out, using another way.

https://github.com/rsnemmen/OpenCL-examples

I'm able to compile it right away, but while executing, i receive following error:

```
    root@atomium:/home/chairman/opencl-experiments/tools-master# ./print-devices
platform 0: vendor 'Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.'
*** 'clGetDeviceIDs' in 'cl-helper.c' on line 134 failed with error 'device not found'.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I found some people having a similar problem using hashcat, but no streamlined generic solution was found.

Maybe someone can point out some steps how to proceed to resolve this issue. (I would prefer to use OpenCL.)

Comment: It looks like your version of the `amdgpu-pro` driver doesn't support your GPU yet. Please try most recent version